# Conditional excel number and formula formatting based on the previous two cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet that looks something like this:

[image: Spreadsheet]

What I want to do here is to do some kind of conditional number formatting, like if I put an item that is counted by the hour like the 'something hourly' row along with the starting and the ending time , the duration column (d2) will be formatted as a time duration in h:mm and will be calculated accordingly.

On the other hand if I put something like an one-time payment and puts time starts and time ends as a hyphen, then the cell (D3) will be formatted as a regular number, so that it can be multiplied with the price per unit altogether.

To make it simple:
A2 (time-based) -> Enters starting and ending time, then D2 will calculate the time duration, and the amount (F2) will be calculated by the duration using the formula (F2*D2*24)

A3 (unit-based) -> Types starting and ending time as a hyphen, treats D3 as a normal number, then F3 will be multiply E3 by D3.

I did found those resources, but I am a loss on how to use it to solve this issue.

https://exceloffthegrid.com/change-number-format-based-on-its-value/

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4

Comment: Just an observation: So, you will have a formula in column D, in preparation to calculate the elapsed time. But in case of row 3 you will enter a number in column D, thus overwriting the formula! If user makes mistake, how will they know how to revert/correct. I suggest you reconsider, maybe split column D into two, one to calculate and show elapsed time, if applicable, the other for the quantity entry. The amount calculation can use alternaitive formulas depending on elapsed time or quantity.

Comment: The data stored in a cell is not dependent by its output format. Format the cell value as a date, as a number, as something else - the result of calculation which uses this cell's value, will NOT alter.

Comment: Yes, you can apply conditional format to the formula cell also, but  using the valid conditions or values. Like the formula cell which has `(F2*D2*24)` can be formatted using logical or relational operates.